# When total_pages column in sys.allocation_units does updates?

Tags: sql-server

I have a table in database that which its size has been grew 15TB in a month. In order to doing further investigation I used this query to find out which column has used more pages.

```
SELECT SUM(DATALENGTHG(column1)),
       SUM(DATALENGTHG(column1)),
       ...
FROM   my_table_name
```

A single column was 14TB. After dropping the column I used below query to make sure the data File is now empty:

```
SELECT 
 OBJECT_SCHEMA_NAME(Parti.object_id) + '.' + OBJECT_NAME(Parti.object_id) AS TableName,
 AU.total_pages/128/1024 AS TotalTableSizeInGB,
 AU.used_pages/128/1024 AS UsedSizeInGB,
 AU.data_pages/128/1024 AS DataSizeInGB
FROM sys.allocation_units AS AU
 INNER JOIN sys.partitions AS Parti ON AU.container_id = CASE WHEN AU.type in(1,3) THEN Parti.hobt_id ELSE Parti.partition_id END
 LEFT JOIN sys.indexes AS ind ON ind.object_id = Parti.object_id AND ind.index_id = Parti.index_id
 inner join sys.objects o on ind.object_id=o.object_id
WHERE 1=1 
AND OBJECT_NAME(Parti.object_id) = 'my_table_name'
```

But still I see the same size.
I tried backing up the log file. Also tried CHECKPOINT and again back log file up. But no difference.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Execute [DBCC CLEANTABLE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/database-console-commands/dbcc-cleantable-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) to reclaim space used by dropped varchar columns.

```
DBCC CLEANTABLE('MyDatabase', 'dbo.my_table_name');
```

Rebuilding the clustered index will also reclaim the space but is more resource intensive.

If you are using the `FULL` recovery model, make sure you perform log backups during the operation to avoid filling the log. `DBCC CLEANTABLE` uses a default batch size of 1000 rows of the optional batch-size argument is not specified.

Answer (score -3):

The command you are looking for is: [`update statistics`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/update-statistics-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16)

Statistic does update automatically, but not too often. The update happens if you have issued changes (`insert`, `update`, or `delete`) to the table, and the count of changes exceed `number_of_rows_at_last_statistic * 0.2`.

If you need more often updates - do it manually.

Comment: I believe [DBCC CLEANTABLE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/database-console-commands/dbcc-cleantable-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) rather than `UPDATE STATISTICS` to reclaim the space.

Comment: @DanGuzman Thank you for your answer. Post your recommendation as answer and it will be accepted.